# biblatex - et al after first author if more than three authors in bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I would like my bibliography to be formatted as:

> FirstAuthor et al.

if the amount of authors is bigger than three. Right now I get:

> FirstAuthor, SecondAuthor, ThirdAuthor et al.

using `maxnames = 3`. Is what I want possible to do? I am using the `biblatex-ieee` style. I have found answers concerning citation in the text, but not the bibliography itself.

Comment: Use the options `[maxnames=3, minnames=1]`.

Comment: That worked, now I feel like an idiot. Thank you!

Comment: I've been told that you can change your comment to an answer, so if you want to do that I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your proposition, but I think it's not necessary (+1 for your answer).

Answer (score 2):

Bernard answered the question in a comment above. The line:

```
\usepackage[maxnames=3, minnames=1]{biblatex}
```

solved the problem.

Comment: Please add an example code which solves the problem

Comment: The content certainly does not justify the downvote (so +1 from me to cancel that out), but it might have been a bit nicer to ask Bernard to convert his comment to an answer. If you only wanted to apply these settings to the bibliography and not the citations you would say `maxbibnames=3, minbibnames=1`.

Comment: Thank you for the tip moewe, didn't realize that was how it worked, I'm still very new to stack. I'll ask him!

Comment: @moewe: That's unimportant: for me, the main point is that the O.P.'s problem be solved.